# WPF DataGrid - Cannot update Sqlite db file with changed values in the GUI on a DataGrid row. It should save the new values via a button click Update

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I'm working on a WPF application that reads data from a SQLite database and render it in a XAML window as a DataGrid.

The program can retrieve the already defined values and show as a DataGrid. The DataGrid name is "lvdevices" and represent a List where the database entries are stored as an Object and inserted into the List. I have succeeded in converting the database entries as each row represent an Object and then add to the lvDevices List by following code.The table in 'db_devices.db' is called 'tbl_devices'.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs
**

````
 public List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();

 public MainWindow(){
       Get_database();
       lvDevices.ItemsSource = devices;

 public class Device
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
 }      
 public void Get_database()
 {
     string dbFilePath = "C:/Users/USERNAME/source/repos/MyWebBrowser/MyWebBrowser/db_devices.db";
     SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={dbFilePath}");
     connection.Open();
     string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_devices";
     SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(query, connection);
     SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

     while (reader.Read())
     {
         //Make device instance
         Device d = new Device();
         // Access individual columns by their indexes or column names
         int id = reader.GetInt32(0); // assuming the first column is an integer
         string name = reader.GetString(1); // assuming the second column is a string
         string ip = reader.GetString(2);
         string user = reader.GetString(3);
         string password = reader.GetString(4);

         d.Id = id;
         d.Name = name;
         d.Ip = ip;
         d.User = user;
         d.Password = password;

         devices.Add(d);
     }
     reader.Close();
     connection.Close();
 }```

**MainWindow.xaml
**
````

UPDATE
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        DELETE

The problem is trying to implement a method that write changes to the database using SQLU(SQLite) command. The changed data manually edited by user in the running application where the user see DataGrid table that is editable. The data should update when a user press on the "UPDATE" button on the same row that update the corresponding rows column values the database. The DataGrid looks like this.

[DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfdP6.png)

I have tried to implement an event on the UPDATE button Click. It goes like this but is a bit messed up right now after countless editing.

```
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string dbFilePath = "C:/Users/PetterEnoksson/source/repos/MyWebBrowser/MyWebBrowser/db_devices.db";

    SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={dbFilePath}");
    connection.Open();

    //These two rows belows is just me fooling around with alternative variables
    var editedRow = lvDevices.SelectedCells[0];
    Device dsa = (Device)editedRow.Item;

    TextBlock _id = lvDevices.Columns[0].GetCellContent(lvDevices.Items[0]) as TextBlock;
    TextBlock _name = lvDevices.Columns[1].GetCellContent(lvDevices.Items[0]) as TextBlock;
    TextBlock _ip = lvDevices.Columns[2].GetCellContent(lvDevices.Items[0]) as TextBlock;

    //string dsa_s = dsa.Name.ToString();

    string query = $"INSERT INTO tbl_devices VALUES Name = {_Name.Text}";
    SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.CommandText = query;

**    //This is where I get an error when clicking the button
**    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
```

The error on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'near "Name": syntax error'.'`

Here is another method I've been fooling around with just as additional reference. It uses Sqlite transaction.

```
public void Write_database(Device new_d)
{
    string dbFilePath = "C:/Users/PetterEnoksson/source/repos/MyWebBrowser/MyWebBrowser/db_devices.db";
    //SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={dbFilePath}");
    using (SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={dbFilePath}"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = $"SELECT * FROM tbl_devices WHERE Id={new_d.Id}";
        SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(query, connection);
        SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //reader.Open();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            using (SqliteTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                string updateQuery = $"UPDATE tbl_devices SET Id = {new_d.Id}, Name = {new_d.Name}, Ip = {new_d.Ip}, User = {new_d.User}, Password = {new_d.Password}";
                using (SqliteCommand _command = new SqliteCommand(updateQuery, connection, transaction))
                {
                    _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", new_d.Id);
                    _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", new_d.Id);
                    _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ip", new_d.Ip);
                    _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", new_d.User);
                    _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", new_d.Password);
                    _command.Transaction.Commit();

                    _command.Transaction.Save("db_devices.db");
                    //reader.Close();
                    _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The part I'm most frustrated with is I don't know how to retrieve the changed values on the DataGrid as a row. Should I use SelectedItem / Selected Cells or lv.Devices.Colums to get the correct values? How does the converting part works if I would like to read each row of changed data as a Device Object and then us the properties to Update the database.

Does the main problem lies within SQL formatting and should I just use SqliteCommand to update changes or SqliteTransaction, either case why?

Is there faults with the data bindings from the DataGrid?

Am I using the wrong EventHandlers?

Thank you very much for any help and sorry for the dirty code. I've been stuck for quite a while and Stack seems like my last resort.